# How can I use Url::fromRoute in my phpunit drupal test

Tags: php, drupal, phpunit

If I crate the class for test like:

```
class ReturnHandlerTest extends OrderKernelTestBase
{
    protected static $modules = [
      'commerce_payment',
      'commerce_payment_example',
    ];


    protected function setUp(): void {
        parent::setUp();
    }
}
```

And if I want to use

```
 Url::fromRoute('commerce_payment.checkout.return', $arguments)
            ->setOptions(['absolute' => true])
            ->toString()
```

in my test case

In the test, I get this exception:

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route "commerce_payment.checkout.return" does not exist.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I should include the module "commerce_checkout".

```
 protected static $modules = [
    'commerce_payment',
    'commerce_payment_example',
    'commerce_checkout',
  ];
```